# "The data reader has more than one field" error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm executing this simple query with Entity Framework

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT * FROM hospital");
```

But I got this error:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

What could be the problem?

Comment: try this db.ExecuteStoreCommand("SELECT * FROM hospital");

Comment: It says that i doesnot contains the definition for ExecuteStoreCommand... Are you missing a using directive or assambly reference ?

Comment: try this db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

Comment: It does not worked neither, in the foreach throw an exception 'cannot convert int to IEnumerable'

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It would be useful to see what the hospital table looks like but assuming something simple like hospital consists of HospitalId and HospitalName then you have a couple of choices.

```
//would work if all you're trying to do is get the Name:
db.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<string>>("SELECT hospitalName FROM hospital"); 

//where you define MyEntity as the same structure as the table would work
db.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>("SELECT * FROM hospital"); 

// would theoretically work although I haven't tried it.  Where the Tuple 
// items would have to match the database types in order.  I.e. if field 1 
// is an int and field 2 is a string then Tuple<int,string>
db.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string>>>("SELECT * FROM hospital");
```

Basically the error is the code doesn't know how to stuff the structure of hospital into a string

Comment: Not all values in the holpital values are string

Comment: the firts one gives a error: "The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types". THe segun one say that the ID is not the same as in the database but its the same. and the last one say: "The result type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor."

Comment: The whole problem is, that the Function SqlQuery needs a Container to squeeze the Result in So SqlQuery<string> would mean you can retrieve at max one field of type string. So you should probably use cgotbergs second example!

Comment: You know, i'll chose the second one. The problem aboud that the ID was not the same as it is in the database was that for some reason i had to add all the fields of the tables to the query string. I mean, i had to write "SELECT hospital_phone, holpital_street, etc, etc FROM hospital", if i write "SELECT hospital_name FROM hospital" the exception occurs...

Comment: Still neither the first or third one works, giving the error "user2195741" mentions

Comment: Using IEnumerable<> always failed with me. I used List<> and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 8):

You might also get this error if you are trying to execute an `INSERT`, `UPATE` or `DELETE` using `SqlQuery` instead of using `ExecuteSqlCommand`

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    int noOfRowUpdated = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update student 
            set studentname ='changed student by command' where studentid=1");

    int noOfRowInserted = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into student(studentname) 
            values('New Student')");

    int noOfRowDeleted = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from student 
            where studentid=1");
}
```

For more details visit -
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 7):

This solved my issue, some results where not getting the way it was supposed to

```
string storedProcedure = "Admin_AutoGenerateKeywordsFortblCompany @Company_ID=" 
                          + CompId;

var s = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<List<string>>("exec " + storedProcedure).ToList();
```

here single or multiple results can be caught

Comment: For an answer in 2016,  you are going old school with ObjectContext,  that is fine , but I would explain that in your code for people.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the secound answer that **cgotberg** gave me, Im going to answer my own question.
 The problem with that code was that some table's field was not the same as it is in the database(I was looking for the exception but I could not found it, sorry for that) but it actually exist.
For some reason i had to add all the fields of the tables to the query string. I mean, i had to write "SELECT **hospital_phone, holpital_street, etc, etc** FROM hospital", if i write "SELECT **hospital_name** FROM hospital" the exception occurs.

Hope I've it explained well.