# C# Writing SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to write a custom query and keep getting back an

> SqlException was unhandled `error' - Incorrect syntax near '.'

Code:

```
var list = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT a.AssetID, a.AssetName, a.Seg1_Code, d.ShortName, e.OfficePercentage, e.MaintenancePercentage" +
           "FROM [Core].[dbo].[Asset] a" +
           "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[AssetAddress] b" +
           "ON a.AssetID = b.AssetID" +
           "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[Address] c" +
           "ON b.AddressID = c.AddressID" +
           "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[StateLookup] d" +
           "ON c.StateID = d.StateID" +
           "INNER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[AssetPayrollMarkupOverride] e" +
           "ON a.AssetID = e.AssetID" +
           "ORDER BY d.ShortName, a.AssetName").ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? Use LINQ...

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as *using* Entity Framework. *Abusing*, or *ignoring*, maybe...

Comment: @RonDeijkers He is using LINQ :) `ToList()`

Comment: I ended up going the LINQ route as suggested by Ron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add space before/after each of your string in concatenation.

```
 var list = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
                    "SELECT a.AssetID, a.AssetName, a.Seg1_Code, d.ShortName, e.OfficePercentage, e.MaintenancePercentage" +
                    " FROM [Core].[dbo].[Asset] a" +
                    " LEFT OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[AssetAddress] b" +
                    " ON a.AssetID = b.AssetID" +
                    " LEFT OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[Address] c" +
                    " ON b.AddressID = c.AddressID" +
                    " LEFT OUTER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[StateLookup] d" +
                    " ON c.StateID = d.StateID" +
                    " INNER JOIN [Core].[dbo].[AssetPayrollMarkupOverride] e" +
                    " ON a.AssetID = e.AssetID" +
                    " ORDER BY d.ShortName, a.AssetName").ToList();
```

*(In the above code I added space before the start of new string)*

Comment: The spaces appears to have worked but now I'm getting another error. 'The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.'

Comment: @Mithrilhall, that is a separate error and requires different context, better if you post a new question with the relevant code and details.For a quick check you may see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932239/error-in-data-reader-in-entity-framework)