# ASP.net MVC 4 - the DataReader has more than one field

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework code-first to call a stored procedure to get one row from a database table.

My procedure code:

```
Drop Procedure SP_Category_DetailByID

Create Procedure SP_Category_DetailByID
    @ID int
as
begin 
    Select * 
    From category 
    Where ID = @ID
end
```

ASP.net code

```
public string getDetail(int id)
{
        object[] sqlParams = 
        {
            new SqlParameter("@ID",id),
        };

        var single = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SP_Category_DetailByID @ID", sqlParams).FirstOrDefault();//or SingleOrDefault()

        return single;
}
```

And the error I get:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in data reader in entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932239/error-in-data-reader-in-entity-framework)