# Inner Join In SqlQuery Giving Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to perform this query :

```
List<string> info = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("
   SELECT u.Name, a.LName 
   FROM dbo.Table1 u 
   INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 a ON a.Table1id = u.id 
   WHERE u.Name = '" + name + "'").ToList();
```

When I try and do that query I get this error:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid
>   for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

When I just tried to select the Name without the inner join it worked fine so how do I fix that so that I can perform my inner join without errors?

Thanks!

Comment: There no errors with `JOIN`, error with two fields in select. With join or without.

Comment: Ok, so how do I fix that and be able to select the data that I need?

Comment: Are you trying to get just a single string? You need to concatenate the columns for that, or define that you're fetching more than just one string.

Comment: Just `SELECT u.Name FROM` or `SELECT a.LName FROM`. Error says - only one field can be palced in select statement.

Comment: @xdd I need both of those fields though

Comment: I'd strongly advise you to revisit your code using an object. In this way you will have db.Database.SqlQuery<yourobject> where you object contains all proprieties that "Select" get back to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in data reader in entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932239/error-in-data-reader-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Both fields if which way? in two strings or in one strihg? for example you can `SELECT u.Name +  a.LName FROM`

Comment: @xdd I need them both as one string

Comment: then use example above with `+`

Comment: @xdd Thanks! works well. Is there any way that I can split them up later like adding in | or something like that?

Comment: @user3681937 `SELECT u.Name + '|' + a.LName FROM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @xdd said worked well

```
List<string> info = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("
   SELECT u.Name + a.LName 
   FROM dbo.Table1 u 
   INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 a ON a.Table1id = u.id 
   WHERE u.Name = '" + name + "'").ToList();
```

Fixed that